# Return a list based on the value of a cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I am trying to do in excel is to return a droplist of values depending on the value of another cell.  For example

Cell A1 could contain two 3 values, Country1, Country2 or Country3.

Depending on which country is in cell A1, cell B1 will display a dropdown of up to 4 other values specific to that country.

Does that make sense?  And if it does, does anyone have a solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Beware : This will require VBA.

Comment: Ah, that I am unable to use due to IT restrictions.

Comment: Actually, there is a way. I'm writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on the article
[How to Create a Dependent Drop Down List in Excel](https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/).

The article describes how a drop-down list can contain
items that are dependent on the selection made in the first drop-down list.
So when you make the selection in Drop Down 1, the options listed in
Drop Down List 2 would automatically update.

The end result of the following would be:

[image]

Here are the steps to follow:

- Select the cell where you want the first (main) drop down list.
- Go to *Data –> Data Validation*.
  This will open the data validation dialog.
- In the data validation dialog box, within the settings tab, select *List*.
- In Source field, specify the range that contains the items that are to be shown in the first drop down list, which for the example is `=$A$1:$B$1`.
- Click OK. This will create the Drop Down 1.
- Select the entire data set (A1:B6 in this example).
- Go to *Formulas –> Defined Names –> Create from Selection*
  (or you can use the keyboard shortcut Control + Shift + F3).
- In the ‘Create Named from Selection’ dialog box, check the *Top row*
  option and uncheck all the others.
  Doing this creates 2 named ranges (‘Fruits’ and ‘Vegetables’). Fruits named range refers to all the fruits in the list and Vegetables named range refers to all the vegetables in the list.
- Click OK.
- Select the cell where you want the Dependent/Conditional Drop Down list
  (E3 in this example).
- Go to *Data –> Data Validation*.
- In the Data Validation dialog box, within the setting tab,
  make sure *List* is selected.
- In the Source field, enter the formula `=INDIRECT(D3)`.
  Here, D3 is the cell that contains the main drop down.
- Click OK.

Comment: Thank you @harrymc this will work perfectly.